# Setting font color and underline of `highlight SpellBad`

Tags: highlight, spell-checking

I want `hi SpellBad` to be red (`167` or `#fb4934`) and underlined. What I have right now is this:

```
...in vimrc...

setlocal spell
set spelllang=en_gb
inoremap <C-l> <c-g>u<Esc>[s1z=`]a<c-g>u
"#
"
autocmd vimenter * ++nested colorscheme gruvbox

...some setup stuff for gruvbox...

"#Highlighting
hi clear SpellBad
hi SpellBad term=reverse
hi SpellBad cterm=underline ctermfg=235 ctermbg=167 ctermul=167
hi SpellBad gui=undercurl guifg=#282828 guibg=#fb4934 guisp=#fb4934
hi clear SpellCap 
hi SpellCap term=reverse
hi SpellCap cterm=underline ctermfg=235 ctermbg=167 ctermul=167
hi SpellCap gui=undercurl guifg=#282828 guibg=#fb4934 guisp=#fb4934
```

This has succeeded differentiating misspelled words. And make them blink incessantly...

`:hi SpellBad` gives this:

```
SpellBad    xxx (blinking) term=reverse cterm=undercurl ctermul=167 gui=undercurl guisp=#83a598
```

I do everything from terminal.

How do I get my misspelled words to be red and underlined?

Imaginary bonus points: ignore misspelling in comments so it is the regular `Comment` style

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

There are two parts to this problem: the blinking and the color

Let's start with the blinking (because it's easier to understand):

I was including `ctermul`, this doesn't really work for some reason and by removing this, the blinking stopped.

For the bad color:
I put the highlight changes in an autocommand, like so:

```
function! MyHighlights() abort
    hi SpellBad term=NONE cterm=underline ctermfg=xxx gui=undercurl guifg=#yyyyyy
endfunction
...stuff...

augroup MyColors
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme * call MyHighlights()
augroup END

...stuff...

autocmd vimenter * ++nested colorscheme gruvbox
```

Replace `xxx` with a number 0 to 256 (as for the 256 colors of terminal) and `yyyyyy` with whatever hex color code. You can get rid of the `cterm` or `gui` variables if you don't use terminal vim or gVim respectively. For more things you can customize the colors of, check out `:h hi`, `:h hl-ColorColumn` (`:h hl-SpellBad` brings you to the same place but `ColorColumn` is at the top of the list), and `:hi`.

The only annoyance now is that misspelled words in comments are also highlighted. I will edit this once I figure out that issue.

Comment: I would say that comments is the only place where you would want misspelled words to be highlighted.